# Why can't I require a specific commit from "dev-master" for this package?

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I'm trying to install [apigen/apigen](https://github.com/ApiGen/ApiGen) via Composer (specifically, `dev-master`). The latest commit requires [roave/better-reflection](https://github.com/Roave/BetterReflection/commit/c87d856) at a certain commit. I ran into issues where Composer was unable to find that particular reference (#c87d856).

To reproduce the issue, I created a minimal `composer.json` file that requires only that missing package/version:

```
{
    "name": "a-vendor/some-library",
    "type": "library",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "roave/better-reflection",
                "version": "dev-master#c87d856",
                "source": {
                    "type": "git",
                    "url": "https://github.com/roave/BetterReflection.git",
                    "reference": "commit/c87d856"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require-dev": {
        "roave/better-reflection": "dev-master#c87d856"
    }
}
```

I was hoping that adding that repository as a package might work around the issue. I thought the difference between the repo and package name might be the problem). However, I get the same issue, with the message:

> The requested package roave/better-reflection dev-master#c87d856
> exists as roave/better-reflection[0.1.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.2.0,
> 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.2.0, 3.3.0, 3.4.0, 3.5.0, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.10.0, 4.10.x-dev, 4.11.0, 4.11.x-dev, 4.12.x-dev, 4.2.0, 4.3.0, 4.4.0, 4.5.0, 4.6.0, 4.6.1, 4.7.0, 4.8.0, 4.8.x-dev, 4.9.0, 4.9.x-dev, dev-dependabot/composer/doctrine/coding-standard-8.2.0,
> dev-dependabot/composer/infection/infection-0.17.5,
> dev-dependabot/composer/phpstan/phpstan-0.12.48,
> dev-dependabot/composer/phpstan/phpstan-0.12.52,
> dev-dependabot/composer/phpstan/phpstan-0.12.53,
> dev-dependabot/composer/vimeo/psalm-3.16,
> dev-dependabot/composer/vimeo/psalm-3.18.2,
> dev-implement-newInstanceArgs, dev-master#c87d856] but these are
> rejected by your constraint.

You can see that the repository that I added is there at the end of the list, but Composer doesn't pick it up as a match.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I can help Composer locate this version/commit, and have that work for the dependency (apigen/apigen) that requires it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
$ composer req --dev roave/better-reflection:4.12.x-dev#c87d856
```

There is no `master` branch [for that repo](https://github.com/Roave/BetterReflection/branches), and it seems that the branch `4.12.x` has been [aliased](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#why-aliases-) to `4.12.x-dev` ([packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/roave/better-reflection#4.12.x-dev)).

Comment: You are absolutely right - thanks for your keen eyes. The solution in my particular case was `composer require --dev roave/better-reflection:"3.3.0 as dev-master"` (as 3.3.0 is the last version that supports the version of PHP I'm using: 7.1)